# Angular - Redirect based on prefix but drop remaining, non-matched path

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I need to support legacy paths in my application but I want to redirect the user to the new, correct path. So for example, I have the following legacy paths:

`/legacyRoute/subRoute`, `/legacyRoute/anotherSubRoute`

and I want both of those to get redirected to:

`/newRoute`

I found the pathMatch option `prefix` in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#redirecting-routes) but setting my route to:

`{path: 'legacyRoute', redirectTo: 'newRoute', pathMatch: 'prefix' }`

results in a path that looks like `/newRoute/subRoute`

It's not a huge problem, the page still loads like I expect but it's bothering me nonetheless. Is there an Angular way to redirect based on a prefix and drop anything that doesn't match? Also, it would be nice if I can keep my query string parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dangit, found a solution right after posting. You can specify a subroute and not do anything with it like this:

`{path: 'legacyRoute/:subRoute', redirectTo: 'newRoute', pathMatch: 'prefix' }`

and that will result in:
`legacyRoute/whatever?blah=blah` -> `newRoute?blah=blah`